# Windows Server doesn't connect to a network share

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

Windows Server doesn't connect to a network share.
Network share is working.

```
Pinging IP with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
Ping statistics for IP:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

net view \\shareaddress

System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
```

When I connected the network share I observed this error message:

> "Mapped disk letter" refers to a location that is unavailable. It
>   could be on a  hard drive on this computer, or on a network. Check to
>   make sure that the  disk is properly inserted, or that you are
>   connected to the Internet or your  network, and then try again. If it
>   still cannot be located, the information  might have been moved to a
>   different location

The network share was mounted via Group Policy.

Perchance anyone knows how I can avoid this error?

When the OS has been restored from the disk problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs some clarity. Pinging an IP address of a machine does not necessarily mean that the share is working. Can you connect to the share from other machines?

The syntax of the NET VIEW command requires a server name as the argument. Supplying a full UNC path (\\servername\sharename) will give the error 53 that you are getting. Try

NET VIEW \\servername

and see what comes back.

If you have admin rights on the remote system (assuming the share is on a Windows box and not a NAS drive or similar), can you connect to the admin shares (C$ etc)?

Comment: The problem was resolved when the OS has been restored from the disk